# How to run insert update statement for last 365 days in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an insert update stored procedure where I am getting data from one procedure and updating in a  table.

My problem is I need to update each day data for last 1 year in the table.

Say for now If I need yesterdays data I need to give my date filter as 1daysprior
2 days before data 2daysprior
...........................
365daysprior

Need to run the procedure for 365 days, which takes a huge effort

Is there any way we can run this at a time.

Sample data:

```
TrendStartDate  TrendEndDate    ToTalCalls  AbnTime
2019-12-22      2019-12-22      42          0
2019-12-21      2019-12-21      464         1016
```

Expected Output:

```
TrendStartDate  TrendEndDate    ToTalCalls  AbnTime
2019-12-20      2019-12-22      42          0
2019-12-19      2019-12-21      464         1016
2019-12-18      2019-12-19      232         121
2019-12-17      2019-12-18      121         22
2019-12-16      2019-12-17      242         3
2019-12-15      2019-12-16      32          3
2019-12-14      2019-12-15      3221        1
2019-12-13      2019-12-14      11          1
```

This needs to go up to 365 days back

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE YourdateColumn > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()`? What are you *actually* asking here?

Comment: @Larnu I dont want to run my statement for each day for 365 days.So need to get any alternate solution to run all the 365 days data at a time

Comment: @Raja If you use `WHERE` you won't be running your statement once for each date. You'll run it once and cover all dates. Unless you want to ask something completely different? Like calculate a running total for the last 365 days?

Comment: That doesn't run a statement for each day; it runs **one** statements; that's where the `WHERE` is on `YourDataColumn` @Raja. An `UPDATE` can effect 0 to infinite rows.

Comment: @Raja edit the question and explain the business problem, not how you think it can be solved. Calculating running totals for example is easy using the `OVER()` clause and window functions in SQL Server 2014+. If you need to calculate day-to-day or even year-on-year differences you can use windowing functions like `FIRST_VALUE`, `LAST_VALUE`, `LEAD` or  `LAG` to get the first, last, next or previous row's value in a set. Eg: `Amount` - LAG(Amount,1) OVER(... ORDER BY Date desc)` will calculate the day-over-day difference of an amount

Comment: `ROWS BETWEEN` was added in 2012, @PanagiotisKanavos , along with those other function you list/ :)

Comment: @Larnu but it's no longer supported :P. In reality, I went from 2K8R2 straight to 2014 so I always had to look up versions in the docs to see what was released when. That doesn't work after the move to `learn.microsoft.com` - [the doc page claims FIRST_VALUE wasn't available in 2014!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014)

Comment: @Larnu I edited the question and added the sample and expected data

Comment: @Raja post the sample and expected data *as text in the question itself*. Images can't be copied and executed. That image doesn't explain what you want to do either, people have to guess how 2 rows become 8 rows, or where the data come from

Comment: @Raja if the question is `How can I update a target table with data pulled from a sproc` then a) this image doesn't help at all and b) you can store a stored procedure's result into a temporary table and then use an `UPDATE target FROM source JOIN target` to update the target with data from matching rows in the source.

Comment: @Raja you can't `UPDATE` a row that doesn't exist. That's called an `INSERT`. The ball park your are aiming for is constantly changing and what you are after is completely unclear.

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '2015-01-01'
SET @EndDate =@StartDate - 365 days


WHILE (@StartDate > @EndDate)
BEGIN
    set startdate=startdate-1 days

END
```

You can use below code snippet. please check syntax for this. in this it will goes to last 365 days loop.

Comment: A `WHILE` is a truly slow way to do anything in an RDBMS; set based methods are far better. Don't use this. There are very few times you need a `WHILE` loop like this in SQL Server.